# Update List<model> items if there are any changes in UI

Tags: c#, html, blazor, antd

This is a bit hard to explain without showing the full concept, but I will try. I have table of Employees in `Record.razor.cs` - `this.PersonellData`. I am adding new Employee into table by this method:

```
private void AddNew()
{
  this.PersonellData.Add(new Personell
  {
    Id = i + 1,
    Name = "John " + i,
    From = DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan(8, 30, 0),
    Category = this.selectedCategoryValue,
  });

  this.DiaryRecord.Employees = new List<Personell>(this.PersonellData);

  i++;
}
```

However after adding employee I would like to change category and (From) time in UI. I am able to do it in UI, but data is not changing in `List<model>` itself. I set breakpoint at

```
private async Task OnCreateNewDiaryRecord()
{
  if (true)
  {
    this.DiaryRecordModel = new DiaryRecord
    {
      Id = this.DiaryRecordModel.Id,
      Title = this.DiaryRecordModel.Title,
      Description = this.DiaryRecordModel.Description,
      Employees = this.DiaryRecordModel.Employees,
      Date = this.SelectedDate,
    };

    await OnInitializedAsync();
  }
  isDialogVisible = false;
}
```

in Index.razor.cs there are no changes I have done in UI to each employee in the list. Any suggestions how to get it working? Should I add methods like OnChange for each UI item, but how to proceed forward with updating actual list?

Here is DiaryRecord.cs:

```
  public class DiaryRecord
  {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Personell> Employees { get; set; }
  }
```

Here is UI part of list items

```
    <Table DataSource="this.PersonellData" RowClassName="@(_=>"editable-row")" Bordered Size=@TableSize.Small>
      <Column Title="From" TData="DateTime">
        <TimePicker TValue="DateTime?" @bind-Value="@context.From" OnChange="this.OnDateValueChanged" />
      </Column>
      <Column Title="Category" DataIndex="@nameof(context.Category)" TData="string">
        <Select DataSource="@this.CategoryList"
                @bind-Value="@this.selectedCategoryValue"
                LabelName="@nameof(Category.CategorySymbol)"
                ValueName="@nameof(Category.CategorySymbol)"
                DefaultActiveFirstItem="false"
                EnableSearch
                OnSelectedItemChanged="this.OnSelectedCategoryChangedHandler">
        </Select>
      </Column>
    </Table>
```

I have tried with `OnChange="this.OnDateValueChanged"`, but don't know how to proceed forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call OnInitializedAsync() from your own code. And when you do it will not trigger a UI update.

```
//await OnInitializedAsync();
await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);  // Invoke probably not needed. Just in case.
```

Comment: If not needed, please remove it, especially because you do not provide any explanation.